# Match pattern and highlight it in modeline for a specific filetype

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I need to match `Issue` in `.conf` filetype and highlight it with custom color but set in mode line instead of a fix in `syntax/conf.vim` file.

The use-case is for each kind of document I need to highlight a specific pattern, `Issue` in this file, and other may be `NOTE`

Comment: Not possible. You cannot do this using a modeline.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Maybe it would be worth to make an answer saying it's not possible to avoid unanswered questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this using modelines, but based on the [vimrc](/questions/tagged/vimrc) tag, I assume a solution that involves adding code to your `.vimrc` is acceptable. If so, you could try something like:

```vim
function! s:confhighlight()
    let l:matches = matchlist(getline('$'), '^# highlight: \(.*\)$')
    if len(l:matches)
        let s:matchid = matchadd('Todo', l:matches[1])
    endif
endfunction

function! s:confunhighlight()
    if exists('s:matchid')
        call matchdelete(s:matchid)
        unlet s:matchid
    endif
endfunction

augroup confhighlight
    autocmd!
    au BufEnter *.conf call s:confhighlight()
    au BufLeave *.conf call s:confunhighlight()
augroup END
```

This will search for a line matching the pattern `# highlight: foo` at the bottom of every .conf file, and highlight `foo` within that file if such a line is found. (Note that this treats `foo` as a case-sensitive regex pattern.)

Comment: Thanks, but it's weird that I can't make it work. I have line contain "test" and the bottom line is `# highlight: test guifg=#C792EA`. `test` wasn't highlighted.

Comment: I got an error: `error detected while processing function <SNR>5_confunhighlight: line 2: E803: ID not found: 5`

Comment: @TuyenPham The function as written only expects a keyword, not a color (e.g. `# highlight: test`. If you'd like to change the color, you can add `highlight Todo guifg=#C792EA` to your vimrc as well.

Comment: How to highlight multiple word, for e.g: `# highlight: test abc` to highlight both `test` and `abc`?