# Highlight multiple words from modeline-like tag?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I am using a function in my vimrc to detect contents similar to those of a modeline and use that to highlight specific words in the file contents.

The function I'm using is from the answer to [my previous question on the topic](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17116/match-pattern-and-highlight-it-in-modeline-for-a-specific-filetype):

```
function! s:confhighlight()
    let l:matches = matchlist(getline('$'), '^# highlight: \(.*\)$')
    if len(l:matches)
        let s:matchid = matchadd('Todo', l:matches[1])
    endif
endfunction
```

How can I modify this function to highlight multiple words instead of just one expression?

You can see that here, we're trying to match `\(.*\)$')` but that would match only all characters till the end of the line.

I want to match words separated by spaces as below:

```
# highlight: first second
```

I expect that all matches of `first` and `second` will be highligted in the current buffer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as mentioned in your other question, this is not possible from a modeline. You need to create a custom plugin for that.

Comment: In link it worked for a word only, how to have it works for multiple words separated by spaces? I just need a simple script for the case, I have no power to write a vimL script/plugin.

Comment: read the answer again. It should work with any keyword, not just one, you just need to add several lines for every keyword you like to have highlighted

Comment: Does “\(.*\)$” only match for one word till the end of line? As I wrote in “expected” but I’ll test it again, I want all matchs contain “first” or “second” highlighted.

Comment: Yes and the easy solution from your other question is to add several lines. The script can be improved to allow several alternative keywords per line, but that needs some vimscript knowledge

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt The script from the other answer only matches on `getline('$')`, so adding multiple lines won't help... This should be fixable with a small tweak to that script, but I feel we should improve this question first...

Comment: Yes, add multiple lines of “# highlight: <..>” won’t help. I would try to solve this if I have some knowledge about vimL but I don’t. What would need to improve this question? @filbranden

Comment: @TuyenPham Can you please rephrase your question to make it more clear? First, mention explicitly that you're using `matchlist(getline('$'), '^# highlight: \(.*\)$')` to get a keyword to highlight in your file. Possibly include the whole function that does that. Only link to the other question for more context (this question should stand on its own, without having to visit that one.) Then ask the question of how to modify that function to support multiple keywords, perhaps multiple ones on the same line, or one per line, whatever works for you...

Comment: Second, stop saying "modeline" directly, this is not really a modeline and using this term will trigger misunderstandings for people who have a clear definition of what they are. Instead, explain that you're looking for something that works "similarly to how modelines work" or something "akin to modelines" but limit yourself to that. I would avoid the word "modeline" in the subject altogether!

Comment: Once you improve the question, I'm sure you should get great answers here!

Comment: @filbranden: Thanks, hope it get better now.

Comment: @TuyenPham I further simplified your question, please revert or further edit if you disagree. I think there's an easy solution using `split()` and a `for` loop but I'd have to test it... Will try to do so later on. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@filbranden](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/18609/filbranden) suggested, there's a simple solution using `split` and a `for` loop, here it is:

```
function! ClearConfHilights()
    for id in getwinvar(win_getid(), 'confHiIds', [])
        call matchdelete(id)
    endfor
    let w:confHiIds = []
endfunction
function! Confhighlight()
    call ClearConfHilights()
    let l:raw_matches = matchlist(getline('$'), '^# highlight: \(\S.*\)$')
    if len(l:raw_matches) >= 1
        let l:matches = split(l:raw_matches[1])
        for match in l:matches
            call add(w:confHiIds, matchadd('Todo', match))
        endfor
    endif
endfunction

autocmd BufWinEnter *.conf call Confhighlight()

" To auto update highlights:
autocmd TextChanged,InsertLeave *.conf if line('.') == line('.') | call Confhighlight() | endif

" To update the highlights when you hit `<F2>`:
nnoremap <F2> :<C-u>call Confhighlight()<CR>
```

---

There are 2 functions here:

- **ClearConfHighlights**
  Its role is to delete all the present conf highlights, and initialize the highlights list to an empty array.
- **Confhighlight**
  Looks at the last line of the file to find (or not) the pattern `# highlight: ...`, and highlights the words one by one, adding them to the highlight list at the same time.

The `autocmd` is here to reset the highlight on buffer change

---

#### Note

As you can see, the highlight list is local to windows, and not buffers. That's because the matches created by `matchadd` are themselves local to windows.

Comment: Looks great, thanks for taking the time to write an answer and test it! A couple of minor nitpicks: 1) You don't need to pass a pattern since `split()` defaults to splitting on whitespace already, so `split(l:matches[1])` is enough. 2) I'd avoid reassigning it and just use it in the `for` directly: `for match in split(l:matches[1])`. Hmmm I just noticed that `s:matchid` now might need to be a list and you might need to clear them appropriately too? (See linked original question for that...) Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your comment @filbranden, I updated my answer!

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I think you're missing clearing the list if it had any elements, right? You might want to include the function that clears them later, since that one will also need to be updated. (In fact, it's just the beginning of this one, right?) (I "like" how these always snowball into something much larger than it seemed initially...)

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, I did forget to clear the list indeed! it looks good to me now, would you add/change something? :)

Comment: Thanks for all your patience! I guess one last issue is that making this a global list will be a problem if you open more than one file with these `# highlight: ...` tags... It would probably be better to make it a buffer-local variable instead. To handle the case where the list doesn't exist, you can use `get(b: 'confHiIds', [])` which will return you an empty list if it doesn't. For example, `let b:confHiIds = get(b: 'confHiIds', [])` will ensure it exists and default it to an empty list. If you could test this all for good measure, that would be great! Thanks again!!! :-D

Comment: Haha, as you said, the snowball effect! :)

Comment: Thanks for your awesome helps. How to auto refresh buffer when we add or remove matches after `highlight: `? :)

Comment: I just updated my answer to include that.